# cant push notification by date in kotlin

Tags: android, push-notification, kotlin, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I try to push notification by date to my app. I allready build the broadcast reciever and for some reason it didn't push the notification.

This is my code:

```
saveTime?.setOnClickListener()  //save time notification
    {
        val hour: Int = tp!!.hour
        val min: Int = tp!!.minute
        var text = "" + hour + ":" + min
        var calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,1)
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY)
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        val intent = Intent()
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.activity,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        var alarmManager = this.activity.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent)
    }
```

And here you'll see my broadcast reciever class:

```
class MyReciver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val timeAlert = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val notificationManager = context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val notificationIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        notificationIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        //val alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        val notification = Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("some title:")
                .setContentText("some text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon_background)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(timeAlert)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build())
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you declare the `MyReciver` in `Manifest.xml`?

Comment: i did.. in this way: <receiver
            android:name="com.example.royok.finalproject.MyReciver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":remote" /> @FAЯAƸ